# Why "alert" always show the first one?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i dont understand why it is always pop-up the 1st alert no matter what i input it right or wrong. Can you help me take a look at my code and show me what i have done wrong. Thank you very much.

```
<script>
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    myapp.controller('Alerts', function getAlerts($scope, $http) {

        $scope.name = null;
        $scope.host = null;
        $scope.searchs = [];
        $scope.hide = false;

        $scope.getSearch = function(name, host) {
            $scope.hide = $scope.hide = true;
            var data = {
                name: name,
                host: host
            };
            var url = "https://h2kgcp144d.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Testing-midterm/rds-search-alert-info";

            $http.post(url, data)
                .then(
                    function(response) {
                        $scope.searchs = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                        alert('Alerts found!');
                        //$scope.hide = false;
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        alert('Failed to search!');
                        //$scope.search = false;
                    });
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  Why do you think it should show the second alert?

Comment: Your response from the server is code 200? If so, the first callback will always be called.

Comment: Your request doesn't fail, it just returns an empty resultset. An empty resultset isn't an "error".

Comment: If you only want to throw an error to see how it behaves just add a fake URL and it'll throw a 404 and you'll get your error alert

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful  comment for me to realize what is going on, the status response 200 so it not an error.

Answer (score -2):

You set the alert on both success and failure case. If this is what you want, then remove the alert from the success case:

```
function(response) {
                    $scope.searchs = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                    //$scope.hide = false;
                },
```